# How to get response of AWS for upload link in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-s3, asp.net-web-api

I want to implement uploading images from Client-Side directly to an `AWS S3` bucket.

I found a good tutorial in YouTube that show how to do it. [Tutorial Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGYeYJpRWPM&ab_channel=SamMeech-Ward)

But it's just for JavaScript.

I writing my program using ASP.NET core & I don't have any idea how to get the link from the AWS on the Back-End.

If you have done something similar, It would be great to share it with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, remember about limitations:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TGetPreSignedUrlRequest.html
>
> This final example creates a URL that allows a third party to put an object, then uses it to upload sample content. The URL is set to expire in 10 days.
>
> GetPreSignedURL sample 5

```
// Create a client
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client();

// Create a CopyObject request
GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
{
    BucketName = "SampleBucket",
    Key = "Item1",
    Verb = HttpVerb.PUT,
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(10)
};

// Get path for request
string path = client.GetPreSignedURL(request);

// Prepare data
byte[] data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Sample text.");

// Configure request
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = WebRequest.Create(path) as HttpWebRequest;
httpRequest.Method = "PUT";
httpRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

// Write data to stream
Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
requestStream.Close();

// Issue request
HttpWebResponse response = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```